# javascript async body not called

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm issuing an async request on a button press:

On html body load, the init function provide a handler to the submit event of the form. This handler actually does the async request.

Here are two solutions. The first one, which can be called the "direct one" works nicely. The second (the "undirect one") does not.
The difference is the way the submit handler is affected. I expected both solutions to be equivalent but with the second one, the code inside async is never called. Why?

**First**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />

<head>
    <title>Radio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function set_fields() {
        }

        function onload() {  
            myForm.onsubmit = async (e) => {    // Direct call
                e.preventDefault();

                const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

                const formData = new FormData(form);
                const jsonObject = Object.fromEntries(formData);
                const jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

                console.log(jsonString);

                let response = await fetch('/set', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: jsonString
                });
            };
        }  

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="onload()">
    <form id="myForm">
        <p>
            <input type="number" name="txtFrequency"
                class="source" />
        </p>
        <p>
     <button type="submit" name="set" class="volume">OK</button>

        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />

<head>
    <title>Radio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function set_fields() {
            async (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();

                const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

                const formData = new FormData(form);
                const jsonObject = Object.fromEntries(formData);
                const jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

                console.log(jsonString);

                let response = await fetch('/set', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: jsonString
                });
            };
        }

        function onload() {
            myForm.onsubmit = set_fields;   // call via a function pointer
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="onload()">
    <form id="myForm">
        <p>
            <input type="number" name="txtFrequency"
                class="source" />
        </p>
        <p>
     <button type="submit" name="set" class="volume">OK</button>

        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `if (!response.ok)` and not `if (response != 'ok')`. `response` is a `Response` object and not a string. Also, you create an anonymous function expression inside `set_fields` but never use or call it, that's probably your main problem.

Comment: response.ok: You're right but that's not the reason of my question (I'll change the question). Anonymous function: I thought it would be called when the user clicks on button ( the onload function does "myForm.onsubmit = setFields;" ). Coming from C, this I what I expected but I migth be wrong...

Comment: `myForm.onsubmit = set_fields` means that `set_fields` runs when you submit the form. `set_fields` has no argument, so you're (a) throwing the event away and (b) the function "does nothing" in that the only code inside `set_field` is code that makes a function. It doesn't _call_ anything. And even if it did, since `set_fields` doesn't have parameters, it wouldn't be able to do pass the event through. Just make `set_fields` async, and make it run the code that you wrapped.

Comment: But on a "writing proper JS" note: use JS naming conventions. Functions and variables use lowerCamelCase, not lower_snake_case (that's Python, not JavaScript). Also, put your code in its own file, then load that file with `<script src="..." async defer></script>` in the `<head>` so the JS gets downloaded and parsed at the same time as your page, but won't _run_ until after the page is ready for updates. That way you can load your JS "as JS" in whatever code editor you're using, and it can help flag problems. Also note that `<script>` only needs a `type` attribute if the content is _not_ JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example:

> ```
> myForm.onsubmit = async (e) => {
> ```

You assign a function to the `onsubmit` property of a form.

When the form is submitted a submit event is triggered which will cause that event listener to be run.

---

In the second example:

> ```
> myForm.onsubmit = set_fields;
> ```

You assign the `set_fields` function in the same way.

The `set_fields` function is run when the form is submitted. The problem is that **it doesn't do anything**.

Inside `set_fields` you have:

> ```
> function set_fields() {
>     async (e) => {
> ```

It creates another function, but does nothing with it. It doesn't assign it anywhere. It doesn't call it. It doesn't even log it. It does *nothing* with that function.

You probably wanted:

```
const set_fields = async (e) => {
```